# Read .txt table from PHP

Tags: php, text-files

I'm new in PHP. I'm trying to design a simple Glossary for Primary English Students.

I want to use a .txt as database, exploded by ":". I've got a txt like this:

```
Hola:Hello
Good Bye: Adios
Car:Coche
Banana:Plátano
Plane:Avión
```

By the moment I know how to print the whole text or one column, but can't print a single word:

```
 <?php 

$file = fopen("bank.txt", "r");

while(!feof($file)) {

echo fgets($file). "<br />";

}

fclose($file);

?>
```

How can I print only ONE SPECIFIC WORD?
e.g. What code is recquired to print only the second word of the third line?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us your code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a minute to take the tour of the site and learn how to ask questions. For example: we won't write code for you. Take the time to add your actual code and explain what is going wrong with that.

Comment: So where are we with this question now?

Comment: It was great, Jan's answer was just great for my current and future needs.

Just can't link his answe to my .txt as $data = fopen("database.txt", "r"); is not working now...

Comment: @Kagarin Then ask him, how you should use his answer; And the other answers didn't helped you ?

Comment: Yours too @Rizier123! thank you!

Comment: @Kagarin So did it worked as you want/expected? (Also see this comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330973/read-txt-table-from-php?noredirect=1#comment48757681_30330973)

Comment: Your code prints this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => : ) [1] => Array ( [0] => : ) [2] => Array ( [0] => : ) [3] => Array ( [0] => : ) [4] => Array ( [0] => : ) )  @Rizier123, If you could help me with that, your answer would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments... in the future you should inform yourself how to ask questions on SO.

Regarding your question, you should take a look at the explode-function and foreach-loops of PHP.

Example:

```
$data = 'Hola:Hello
Good Bye: Adios
Car:Coche
Banana:Plátano
Plane:Avión';

$arrData = array();

$lines = explode( "\n", $data );
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $words = explode( ":", $line );
    $arrData[] = array( $words[0], $words[1] );
}

echo( $arrData[2][1] );
// Prints: "Coche"
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jan. Think I should log out and keep reading php manuals for a while. My problem now is that $data = fopen("database.txt", "r"); is not working now... This is embarrasing

Comment: Thanks so much @Jan. Think I should log out and keep reading php manuals for a while. My problem now is that $data = fopen("database.txt", "r"); is not working now... This is embarrasing

Comment: check the `file_get_contents`-function to get the content of a file. https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then go through each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the line by a `:` colon.

```
<?php       

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(":", $v);
    }, $lines);

    print_r($lines);  //echo $lines[0][1] <- Will print the first line, second word

?>
```

Or what you could also do, is change your file into a `.ini` file format, e.g.

```
Hola="Hello"
Good Bye="Adios"
Car="Coche"
Banana="Plátano"
Plane="Avión"
```

And then you can simply use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $file = parse_ini_file("test.ini");
                              //^^^^ See also here the extension
    print_r($file);

?>
```

Comment: Your code prints this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => : ) [1] => Array ( [0] => : ) [2] => Array ( [0] => : ) [3] => Array ( [0] => : ) [4] => Array ( [0] => : ) )

Comment: Otherwise yours would be simpler, and better i guess

Comment: @Kagarin ah sorry, messed some arguments up, just reload the page and the code should work; and you get your simple solution

Comment: I'm so sorry @Rizier123 but I feel I'm bothering you; now it prints Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Hola [1] => Hello ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Adiós [1] => Good Bye ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Car [1] => Coche ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Banana [1] => Plátano ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Plane [1] => Avión ) ) Hello 

I just want it to print one word :(

Comment: @Kagarin What else do you want then? Please make an example in your question

Comment: Solved @Rizier123, whenever i can rate you i will. Thanks so much for your attention